# Where do I inject sensitive password data in the development build process?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

My asp.net core 2.2 project has 2 settings files:

- appSettings.json
- appSettings.development.json

They contain the general non-sensitive settings and are included in our git repo.  In local development I am using the Visual Studio feature of User Secrets to merge sensitive password data at runtime so that no password data ever makes it into the git repo.

My build process happens inside a docker file.  The dockerfile copies the project, restores dependencies and builds so that the project can be easily built from the repo with minimum fuss.

Where should I add the sensitive data to appSettings.json?  What would be a good approach?

I could manually add it to appSettings.json after repo clone before running but I am a bit concerned someone would commit it to repo by accident.  Any best practice approach here?

Comment: Do you want to use the secrets at docker build time itself ?  An approach I've seen being used is that secrets are passed as enviroments variables during `docker run`. the startup script, detemplatizes `appSettings.json` using those ENV variables.

Comment: Is this docker image going to be used locally or is it to be distributed? If it's going to be local, would it be feasible to just mount the directory where the credentials are stored into the docker, rather than copying them anywhere?

Comment: @sairamch04 That sounds like a good approach.  Do you know of any examples I could look at to get an understanding of it?

Comment: @EdGrimm at the moment we are installing dependencies like database locally for development but plan to move it all into a docker compose so it doesn't require any local configuration but initially we just want to get a production image that we can hook in a CI pipline for production.